# Import from another sheet using QUERY IMPORTRANGE but query where is from current sheet

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm using query and import range to get from another sheet. Example

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("KEY","Form Responses 1!A:L"), "select * where J = '2020-02-01' ")
```

I want the where part of the query to be driven from a cell on the current sheet, which contains a date. Something like

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("KEY","Form Responses 1!A:L"), "select * where J = A1")
```

How can I use the value from a cell in the current sheet to drive the import query where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it on cell reference. You have to set the a1 notaion between: '"& A1 &"'

See this post:
[QUERY syntax using cell reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427421/query-syntax-using-cell-reference)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("KEY", "Form Responses 1!A:L"), "where Col10 = "&DATEVALUE(A1))
```